# How to display a SQL stored procedure in VB?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, namespaces

I am using SSMS 2008 and VB.  I'm a novice VB developer.  I am trying to display results of a simple stored proc on my ASPX page.  But I get the error below.  Here is my code behind for the ASPX page:

```
>           MsgBox(GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.GetDevSQLServerStoredProcedure())
```

And my code from GlobalF namespace:

```
Public Shared Function GetDevSQLServerStoredProcedure()
    Dim conn As SQLConnection
    Dim DSPageData As New System.Data.DataSet

    conn = New SQLConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("AMDMetricsDevConnectionString"))
    Dim cmd As New SQLCommand

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "AllTableCount"

    Dim da = New SQLDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(DSPageData)
    Return DSPageData
End Function
```

And my error:

> Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted
>   to type 'String'
>
> [ArgumentException: Argument 'Prompt'
>   cannot be converted to type 'String'.]
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox(Object
>   Prompt, MsgBoxStyle Buttons, Object
>   Title) +320
>   ASP.website_complaints_complainttrendinglist3_aspx.Main()
>   in
>   e:\inetpub\amdmetrics-d.web.abbott.com\wwwroot\Website\Complaints\ComplaintTrendingList3.aspx:113
>   ASP.website_complaints_complainttrendinglist3_aspx.Page_Load(Object
>   Sender, EventArgs E) in
>   e:\inetpub\amdmetrics-d.web.abbott.com\wwwroot\Website\Complaints\ComplaintTrendingList3.aspx:60
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr
>   fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>   +14    System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +35
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +99
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +50    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

This stored procedure just returns number of records in my database.  But I want to perform other stored procedures which return a table.  How do I implement this without errors?

Finally my new SQL SP:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].PrintTestMsg AS BEGIN 
PRINT 'HELLO'
PRINT 'WORLD'
PRINT 'PAGE3'
PRINT 'PAGE4'
END

SELECT * FROM SELECT (EXEC PrintTestMsg)
```

I get syntax error in SSMS with above select.

What about the code below?  Could I get a dataset now?

```
private string DatasetToString(DataSet ds)
{ 

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
DataTable dt = ds.Tables(0);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
sb.Append(“;”);
sb.Append(dt.Rows(1).ToString());
}

return sb.ToString();

}
```

Comment: You're returning a DataSet. You need to do some parsing on that dataset to pull out the string you want the MsgBox to display

Comment: Oh I see what u r saying.  Let me try!

Comment: Prescott, I see why I need to return a string for the MsgBox.  However, I am trying to return just the first row from my stored proc in SSMS but am getting syntax error.  How can I modify this query to just return first row?  See above edits

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SELECT (EXEC PrintTestMsg)`

Comment: Also, you probably want to change your code a bit, 'foreach(DataRow dr in Dt.Rows) { sb.Append(";"); sb.Append(dr(0).ToString()); {'

Comment: Thanks Prescott, but your SQL query above gave me error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about converting the Dataset to a string.  Your real problem here is that you can't use the normal MsbBox() function in asp.net at all.  Really.  If you try, it will display the message on a hidden private desktop on the web server.  It will not pop up the message on the user's machine.  Not only that, but it will block until clicked on, and since it's on a hidden desktop this can never happen.  The result is that your user's page will never load.

What you want to do instead is bind the result of `GetDevSQLServerStoredProcedure()` method to a GridView, DataGrid, or Repeater control.  There are other problems in your code as well, so I'll do a quick clean-up for each part to show you what it should look like:

```
''#Always list the type returned at the end of the method name
Public Shared Function GetDevSQLServerStoredProcedure() As DataSet
    Dim DSPageData As New System.Data.DataSet

    ''# A Using block will ensure the .Dispose() method is called for these variables, even if an exception is thrown
    ''# This is IMPORTANT - not disposing your connections properly can result in an unrespsonsive database
    Using conn As New SQLConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("AMDMetricsDevConnectionString")), _
          cmd As New SQLCommand("PrintTestMsg", conn), _
          da As New SQLDataAdapter(cmd)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        da.Fill(DSPageData)
    End Using

    Return DSPageData
End Function
```

Now, your stored procedure.  This doesn't return anything, so I added code to *also* return the printed data to your page:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].PrintTestMsg AS BEGIN 
    PRINT 'HELLO'
    PRINT 'WORLD'
    PRINT 'PAGE3'
    PRINT 'PAGE4'

    SELECT 'HELLO' AS Msg
    UNION
    SELECT 'WORLD'
    UNION
    SELECT 'PAGE3'
    UNION 
    SELECT 'PAGE4'
END
```

You need to add this to your aspx markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="PrintMessageGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

And, finally, replace your MsgBox() function call with this code:

```
PrintMessageGrid.DataSource = GetDevSQLServerStoredProcedure() 
PrintMessageGrid.DataBind()
```

Note that this is just enough to get things working in a basic sense, so that you can continue to explore ASP.Net.  Some of the techniques I just posted I would never use in a production web site.  Examples include AutoGenerateColumns in the GridView and even datasets (datareader is almost always a better option).  This is just the bare minimum change to your original code so you can start piecing things together and learn better techniques as you get more practice.

Comment: Thanks a million, Joel!  However, when I tried this I got new error: Name 'GetDevSQLServerStoredProcedure' is not declared.  Do you know what type this should be declared as?

Comment: The type is fine here - the problem is where you put it.  Make sure it's inside your page class.  Otherwise, you have to call it using it's class name also.

Comment: How can I thank you?!  It returns the results now!  I am so excited!  Next I'm going to figure out how to execute a stored procedure which has parameters.

Comment: i m curious though...what is the "_" for at the end of the code lines above?  Do I need that?

Comment: @salvationishere It's the VB line continuation character. You could remove it, but then you'd have to put those other variables up on the same line.  I find it much more readable like this.